# Doctrine 2 ODM: Querying ID field with MongoRegex with LIKE

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have a bigger project using Doctrine 2 ODM in a Symfony context.

Given a simple ODM entity as this (XML definition):

```
<document name="\Document\App" repository-class="\Repository\AppRepository">
  <field fieldName="id" type="string" id="true" strategy="UUID"/>
  <field fieldName="name" type="string"/>
</document>
```

I want to query for `App` documents using a `MongoRegex` expression on the `_id` field.

Now, I'm aware of the "`string` versus `MongoId`" problem - all our ID's are proper strings.

When I try to do this via MongoDB shell (using Robomongo as GUI); it's all fine, as this expression successfully returns the objects I'm searching for:

```
App.find({'_id': /^ad.*$/i})
```

But in the PHP context it's different. There is special logic in Doctrine 2 ODM that treats `equals()` search on identifier fields different from normal `equals`.

### Querying a normal field Doctrine 2 ODM behavior

We have the normal field `name` in our `App` entity. If we want to make a like search on that, we do (assuming `$builder` is instanceof `QueryBuilder`)

```
$builder->field("name")->equals(new \MongoRegex("/^ad.*$/i"));
```

If we then check what `QueryBuilder` has done calling `$builder->getQueryArray()`, we see:

```
array (size=1)
 'name' => 
    object(MongoRegex)[628]
    public 'regex' => string '^ad.*$' (length=6)
    public 'flags' => string 'i' (length=1)
```

That's nice and it works.. We have our `MongoRegex` instance in there..

### Querying _id field with MongoRegex Doctrine 2 ODM behavior

It's all different on an identifier field.

Let's do this:

```
$builder->field("id")->equals(new \MongoRegex("/^ad.*$/i"));
```

Now let's check `$builder->getQueryArray()` again:

```
array (size=1)
  '_id' => string '/^ad.*$/i' (length=9)
```

Hm, no `MongoRegex` instance in the query. And indeed, the query doesn't work..

### Finding the cause

This question is not *how does this happen*. I know how - but not *why*.. Let's see the Doctrine 2 ODM code.

This conversion happens in `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Persisters\DocumentPersister` ([see code here](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/1.0.3/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Persisters/DocumentPersister.php#L1004)).

Excerpt:

```
// Process identifier fields
    if (($class->hasField($fieldName) && $class->isIdentifier($fieldName)) || $fieldName === '_id') {
        $fieldName = '_id';
        if ( ! $prepareValue) {
            return array($fieldName, $value);
        }
        if ( ! is_array($value)) {
            return array($fieldName, $class->getDatabaseIdentifierValue($value));
        }
```

If the query value is not an array (what it isn't, it's a `MongoRegex`), it will converted to one and the value will be replaced with the return of `getDatabaseIdentifierValue()` of `ClassMetaDataInfo` ([see call here](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/1.0.3/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L1455)) of the data type (in this case `string`) - which will then be a normal string instead of a `MongoRegex` instance.

### My question

So we know *how* it happens but not *why* - what is the reason for this conversion in `equals()` operations on identifier fields? Is there any need to do that?

How can one query with a Regex on an identifier field using Doctrine 2 ODM? We know it works in the MongoDB shell, why wouldn't it here?

I posted this as a SO question first instead of a Doctrine 2 ODM issue as this is still a question. If nobody knows a reason why this is done, I'll try to raise a Github issue for the ODM maintainers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating this I created a [Github issue](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/1294) explaining the problem and it has been marked as a bug. So it is indeed a buggy behavior..